# Consultar tabla intermedia con datatable en Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo la tabla productos y la tabla clientes, ambas con las columnas:

- id
- nombre.

Y además, una tabla intermedia llamada `clientes_productos` con las columnas:

- cliente_id
- producto_id
- fecha_canje

Los modelos y relaciones ya están realizadas. Lo que necesito en mostrar los productos que canjeo, un determinado cliente junto a su respectiva fecha de canje. Dichos datos necesito mostrarlos en un `datatable`.

Les agradecería si me pueden ayudar.

Lo estoy realizando en Laravel 5.2

Comment: Debes crear una vista que se encargue de mostrar los datos de esa manera. Sería bueno que nos mostraras lo que haz intentado hacer.

Comment: Hola @PabloRivera. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías publicar el código con lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora? Por más que no funcione, ayudará a dar contexto a tu pregunta y será más fácil que alguien te responda tomando eso como base.

Comment: Modelo Cliente: public function productos(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Producto','clientes_productos','cliente_id','producto_id');
    }

Comment: modelo Productos:   public function clientes(){

 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cliente','clientes_productos','producto_id','cliente_id');
    }

Comment: Disculpen, como puedo mandar fotos?, porque no me deja pegar todo el codigo

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Puedes editar tu pregunta haciendo click en el enlace *Editar* debajo de ella. Por otra parte, si vas a subir código que no sea por fotos, si no, copia el código y pégalo en tu pregunta. Para darle formato, selecciónalo y dale click al botón de las llaves (`{}`). Adicionalmente, te recomiedo [hacer el tour](http://es.stackoverflow/recorrido) y leer nuestra guía sobre [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Modelo Cliente:

```
public function productos(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Producto','clientes_productos','cliente_id','producto_id');
    }
```

Modelo Productos:

```
public function clientes(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cliente','clientes_productos','producto_id','cliente_id');
    }
```

ClienteProductoController:

```
public function anyData()
{
$prodCli = DB::ClienteProducto()
    ->where('cliente_id', 1)
    ->orderBy('fecha_canje', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();

return Datatables::of($prodCli)
    ->where('cliente_id', 1)
    ->removeColumn('producto_id')
    ->addColumn('fecha_canje')
    ->addColumn('operaciones', '
            <ul class="icons-list">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <li><a href="{{ URL::route( \'clienteproducto.editar\', array( $id )) }}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Editar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" onclick="eliminar({{ $id  }})"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Eliminar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>')
    ->removeColumn('id')
    ->make(true);
}
```

Listadeproductos.blade.php:

```
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function datos() {

            // Basic initialization
            $('#producto-table').DataTable({
                autoWidth: false,
                responsive: true,
                dom: '<"datatable-header"fl><"datatable-scroll"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
                language: {
                    search: '<span>Filtrar:</span> _INPUT_',
                    lengthMenu: '<span>Mostrar:</span> _MENU_',
                    paginate: { 'primera': 'Primera', 'ultima': 'Ultima', 'siguiente': '→', 'previa': '←' }
                },
                drawCallback: function () {
                    $(this).find('tbody tr').slice(-3).find('.dropdown, .btn-group').addClass('dropup');
                },
                preDrawCallback: function() {
                    $(this).find('tbody tr').slice(-3).find('.dropdown, .btn-group').removeClass('dropup');
                },
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,//evita que la columna con botones sea un parametro en la consulta sql
                "aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': false,"bSearchable": false, 'aTargets': [ 2 ] }],
                ajax: '{!! route('producto.datatable') !!}',
                columns: [
                    {data: 'nombre', name: 'nombre'},
                    {data: 'puntos_producto', name: 'puntos_producto'},
                    {data: 'operaciones', name: 'operaciones'}
                ]
            });
        }
</script>
@endsection
```

Migracion Cliente Producto

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clientes_puntos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('cliente_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('cliente_id')
                ->references('id')->on('clientes');

            $table->integer('punto_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('punto_id')
                ->references('id')->on('puntos');

            $table->date('fecha_carga');
            $table->integer('puntos_cargados');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear un modelo que maneje la tabla, y dejas que Eloquent haga su magia.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductosCliente extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'clientes_productos';
    public function Cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente');
    }
    public function Producto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Producto');
    }
}
```

luego puedes filtrar como te guste:

```
$prodCli= App\ProductosCliente::where('cliente_id', 1)
               ->orderBy('fecha_canje', 'desc')
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```

Tambien puedes hacer relaciones en el modelo Productos o Clientes para tener acceso desde ahi.

Comment: Intente hacer lo informado por @JoseMariaToscano, pero sigo sin poder. Lo que hice fue crear un controlador llamado ClienteProductoController, donde tengo la funcion del datatable que no me funciona:

Comment: public function anyData()
    {
        $prodCli = DB::ClienteProducto()
            ->where('cliente_id', 1)
            ->orderBy('fecha_canje', 'desc')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
        return Datatables::of($prodCli)
            ->addColumn('operaciones', '
            ->removeColumn('id')
            ->make(true);
    }

Comment: Y éste es el script que tengo en el blade  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function datos() {
            $('#productosClientes-table').DataTable({
                autoWidth: false,
                responsive: true,
                dom: '<"datatable-header"fl><"datatable-scroll"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
                language: {
                    search: '<span>Filtrar:</span> _INPUT_',
                    lengthMenu: '<span>Mostrar:</span> _MENU_',},
                drawCallback: function () {

Comment: },
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                "aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': false,"bSearchable": false, 'aTargets': [ 2 ] }],
                ajax: '{!! route('clienteproducto.datatable') !!}',
                columns: [
                    {data: 'nombre', name: 'nombre'},
                    {data: 'fecha_canje', name: 'fecha_canje'},
                    {data: 'operaciones', name: 'operaciones'}
                ]
            });
        }
 </script>

Comment: @PabloRiveraMadrazo Agrega el código que tienes a tu pregunta, no en los comentarios. ;)